# Python - concatenate 2 lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, concatenation

Hi I am new to both Python and this forum.

My question:

I have two lists:

```
list_a = ['john','peter','paul']
list_b = [ 'walker','smith','anderson']
```

I succeeded in creating a list like this using `zip`:

```
list_c = zip(list_a, list_b)
print list_c
# [ 'john','walker','peter','smith','paul','anderson']
```

But the result I am looking for is a list like:

```
list_d = ['john walker','peter smith','paul anderson']
```

Whatever I tried I didn't succeed! How may I get this result?

Comment: Just as a side note, this is not a forum but a question and answer site :)

Answer (score 12):

You are getting zipped names from both the lists, simply join each pair, like this

```
print map(" ".join, zip(list_a, list_b))
# ['john walker', 'peter smith', 'paul anderson']
```

Comment: This just returns a map object

Answer (score 7):

```
List_C = ['{} {}'.format(x,y) for x,y in zip(List_A,List_B)]
```

Comment: I prefer this answer because of its clarity, even though it may be slower than the mapping approach.

Comment: @holdenweb: I usually stick with this method in case some of the array values are not strings.

Answer (score 0):

If list_a and list_b has same length always then try it:

`list_c = [list_a[i]+' '+list_b[i] for i in xrange(0,len(list_a))]`

On the other hand if list_a and list_b may have different lengths then:

```
list_c=[]
for i in xrange(0,len(list_a) if len(list_a)>len(list_b) else len(list_b)):
    merged_item = (list_a[i] if i<len(list_a) else '')+\
                  (' ' if i<len(list_a) and i<len(list_b) else '')+\
                  (list_b[i] if i<len(list_b) else '')
    list_c.append(merged_item)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem is as below:

```
list_d = [] # desired output list
list_a = ['john', 'peter', 'paul'] 
list_b = ['walker', 'smith', 'anderson']

for i in range(len(list_a if len(list_a) < len(list_b) else list_b)):
    f = " ".join([list_a[i], list_b[i]])
    list_d.append(f)
print d
```

The output you will get on executing the above code is:

```
['john walker', 'peter smith', 'paul anderson']
```